# C++ websockets server/client crossplatform linux/windows

Tags: c++, websocket

I am trying to implement a sample code with Websocket client/server:

- works on both windows and linux
- supports multiple clients
- no extra dependencies, pure C/C++ easy to use code

For example, implementing something like a **chat room** that accepts many users, would be a great base for me to understand how Websockets work and use them in my project.

I am looking at [this website](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/libc/html_node/Server-Example.html) and I see this example of Websockets in C++.

I am using Clion IDE which uses MinGW compiler and these headers do not exist:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
```

Auto-code-completion suggests these headers:

```
#include <winsock.h>
or    
#include <winsock2.h>
```

Even though I see no errors on my IDE with those headers, when I run the code I get linking errors:

```
CMakeFiles\server_client.dir/objects.a(server.cpp.obj): In function `main':
C:/Users/Shiro/ClionProjects/server_client/server.cpp:44: undefined reference to `listen@8'
C:/Users/Shiro/ClionProjects/server_client/server.cpp:58: undefined reference to `select@20'
C:/Users/Shiro/ClionProjects/server_client/server.cpp:66: undefined reference to `__WSAFDIsSet@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

On a sidenote, is this code even good to implement a Websocket client/server in C++ ? I want this to work on both windows and linux and have no external dependencies. Just pure C/C++. A couple of libraries I saw (like [libwebsockets](https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets)) were way too confusing and over-complicated to me, and they lack of any documentation or any examples. I did not understand a single line of code. Websockets in other languages like Java or C# are way more straightforward. Can someone point me in the right direction please ?

Answer (score 0):

The windows socket API is very similar to the POSIX one, but there are some differences, as explained in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the fact that you have to call [`WSAStartup()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before using this API.

About the header take the `winsock2.h`.  But you shouldn't forget to include the socket library in your project (either makefile/project parameters or as `#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")`.

If you want portable code, you may want to consider [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/bsd_sockets.html)

Comment: Getting `undefined reference to WSAStartup`. What is `"Ws2_32.lib"` supposed to be ? Do I need to put a path or something ?

Comment: It's supposed to refer to the dll stub for  ws2_32.dll which is in system32 (no need for an additional path).  To lib should however be in one of the path given to the linker (e.g. LIB environmnet variable).

Comment: I don't understand why  I keep getting those `undefined reference` errors

Comment: I am having trouble installing boost with Clion. I have posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519453/setup-boost-in-clion) here if you could help me

Comment: Now the problem has been narrowed down to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520283/how-to-link-ws2-32-in-clion) if you could help. I don't understand how to link the `ws2_32` library . The `#pragma` is MSVC only keyword

Comment: ok ! Much better then.  Ws2_32 is a dll that belongs to the windows system.  In order to tell this to the linker, you need to link your code together with ws2_32.lib.  The pragma is compiler specific.  If this does'nt work for you, you could add the library to the compiling options (e.g. try -lws2_32  or manually add the path to the windows development kit).